# To create proto of the class

Tags: protocols, protocol-buffers

Without list i am able to create a proto of the Order class , But when i started using List inside the Order class it didnot work for me. What will be the proto file

```
public class Order {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private int orderID;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private int quantity;
        private List<String> product;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic starting point might be:

```
message Order {
    optional int32 orderID = 1;
    optional int32 quantity = 2;
    repeated string product = 3;
}
```

I can't tell you what field numbers you want, nor the integer encoding (signed, unsigned, zizag, fixed, etc)